# Parse: withoutDataWithClassName is now outDataWithClassName?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've migrated my iOS parse SDK from the old Parse SDK to the version released to support a Parse stack hosted on my own infrastructure.

I have my project set up with SocketIO and decided it would be more efficient to append new Parse Objects sent from the server to my iOS apps model instead of making a new network request whenever the model changed, therefore I needed to instanciate a Parse object with an existing object ID.

To do that I used the following code snippet:

```
let appendError = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "MachineError", objectId: id)
appendError.setValue(errorCode, forKey: "errorCode")
appendError.setValue(errorMessage, forKey: "errorMessage")
appendError.setValue(newDate, forKey: "createDate")
appendError.setValue(serial, forKey: "serialNumber")
appendError.setValue(status, forKey: "status")
appendError.setValue(false, forKey: "completed")
```

This code used to work fine when I was running xcode v7.1 but since this-morning when I upgraded to xcode 7.3, I was presented with an error that `withoutDataWithClassName` was not a valid parameter, it offered me `outDataWithClassName` as an alternative but the naming of that parameter did not sound as declarative as the previous.   I did some reading through the PFObject documentation for iOS, but I could not find any details depicting what `outDataWithClassName` actually does.

I can only assume that it may be a typo on behalf of the Parse team, but I may be wrong.   Could anyone here confirm whether `withoutDataWithClassName` is equivalent to `outDataWithClassName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a mistake related to automatic Objective-C to Swift conversion. It was reported as in [issue in the repo](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/806), and a fix was committed 3 days ago.

In short, `outDataWithClassName` will do the same thing as `withoutDataWithClassName` for now, but since the current method name is rather uninformative, I would recommend updating Parse soon to get the fix.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my suspicions Kyle, I looked through some of the git issues but must have brushed over this one :)